# Timeout does not log out if windows is locked

Tags: javascript, timeout, sleep

I have been recently working on the timeout function (used javascript - setInterval). I did test it, it worked exactly the way I want apart from one tiny detail. Whenever a logged in user sleeps the computer, the session is still active and timeout keeps counting the time. Consequently, after waking the PC up, let's say after 40 min, the timeout says e.g. -10 min and the user is still logged in. If he clicks anything or refresh the page, the service will refresh and the timeout is being restarted to the initial value like nothing happened (user is still logged in). Is there a way of making sure that the user is going to be logged out after waking the PC up?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: could you provide the relevant code here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, the solution could be to call a script in ajax when the timeout has a value of 0, which will log out the user and then you could refresh the page, the all thing in javascript

Comment: Hi, thank you for an answer. However, it did not work. I did mange to solve it by myself. The thing I did is a jquery listening to different events so e.g. on the button click with the timeleft less than 0 it does log the user out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using setTimeout/setInterval for you logout directly, perhaps try something like this:

```js
var targetTime = moment(new Date()).add(5 ,'s');
var intervalHolder = {};
console.log("go")
intervalHolder.interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (moment(new Date()).isAfter(targetTime)) {
    console.log('TimedOut');
    clearInterval(intervalHolder.interval);
  }
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks I will definitely try it. I have used tock.js before developing the code I use right now and there have been issues with pages using angular for some reason. I know about moment.js, have never used it though. I decided to give up any plugins/libraries to build the timeout after the problem with tock.js.